# open a pop up when querystring matches

Tags: popup, query-string, tooltip

Is there anyway that I can pop up a window with just matching a query string from the url. Sample code is like follows

```
string popup = context.Request.QueryString["raisepopup"];

if (popup == "raise")
 {

 //Here when the query string matches to raise the pop up shoul be displayed with some information which is already grab in this class
}
```

Please help me. Thank you

2#
Thank you

I tried it and it is working fine.

Now I need to extend my question as kinda change in my requirement. Instead of simple popup I want to show a tooltip on querystring. I tried using ToolStripDropDown class but I think it is for WPF application. Mine is pure webofrm application. Is there any chance that I can accomplish this tooltip pop up when query string matches with specific string?

Thank you veru much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using asp.net than you can easily do it using `RegisterStartupScript`

for example

```
if (popup == "raise") {

  string popupScript = "<script language='JavaScript'>" & _
"window.open('RtFileResult.aspx', '', " & _
"'width=750, height=580,
scrollbars,status,menubar,resizable,toolbar,titleb ar,location');" & _
"</script>"

Page.RegisterStartupScript("PopupScript", popupScript)


}
```

Comment: HI Pranay. Thank you very much for your reply. I edited(extended) my question can you have a look into it and please share your thoughts..

Comment: for the tooltip i think you use jquery plugin avaiable for tooltip it good